# iOS: Making only one UIView to respond

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have several UIViews (CollectionView, TextField, etc) in my ViewController. If the user presses any item in the collectionview, a new collectionview (smaller) is to be shown from the bottom.When the new collectionView is being shown, I want only this view to respond to touch events. If the user taps outside this view, it should be taken off the viewController. The functionality is similar to PopOverController. I am using

```
[subCollectionView becomeFirstResponder]
```

but the other views are also responding to touch events.
I wish I could put the question more clearly, Let me know if it is not clear.

Thx!

Comment: when your small view/ popover controller appears make the other view as userinteractionEnable:NO;

Answer (score 0):

No need of setting firstResponder of a UIView.
All you need to do is

1. create a view named bottomAnimateView(which will come from bottm) of size =
   self.view.frame and background color as clear color.
2. add a UICollectionView over it.
3. 3.Add UITapgesture over bottomAnimateView and do the stuff of removing or hidding it from     superView.

Refer the attachment .Which might help you.
[image]